# JSSC DCE Control Lines

Tags: java, serial-port, jssc

I'm looking for a way to develop a DCE (RS232) using Java for an existing legacy protocol which requires me to read the DTR pin status, and maintain control of the DSR and RLSD pins from my end. I went about trying to do this by using JSSC but it seems to have everything I would need to make the DTE side of things such as controlling DTR and picking up DSR events.

Currently, without any setup of the control lines, it seems to use a combination of DTR/DSR and RTS/CTS.

Is there a way for me, using Java, to control the reading of the DTR, and setting of the DSR,RLSD control lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers but I figured it out. Simple answer is to develop as a DTE and use a null modem cable to be a DCE to the other end.